# Помогите, что это за ошибка в коде?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хотел написать бота для вк, и случилась такая ошибка, как ее исправить?

```
import vk_api
import time
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token = "ec47278fbfcec086bb2638b916692a25c470fcd1c6f86cd010327bbc72c540dc46b176c8915dea96f7c38")
vk._auth_token()
uch = []
while  True:
    messages = vk.method("messages.getConversationa",{"offaet": 0, "count": 1})
    if messages["count"] >=1:
         id = messages["items"][0]["conversation"]["peer"]["id"]
         body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
         chat = messages["items"][0]["conversation"]["peer"]["type"]
         typ = messages["items"][0]["conversation"]["peer"]["type"]
         id_own = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
         if typ == "chat":
            if "Луи" in body.lower():
                if id_own == 472427950:
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                else:
                    if "кто" in body.lower():
                        opred = vk.method("messages.getConversationaMembers", {"peer_id": id})
                        count = opred["count"]
                        for i in range(count):
                            first_name = opred["profiels"][1]["first_name"]
                            last_name = opred["profiels"][1]["last_name"]
                            peer = opred["profiels"][1]["id"]
                            message = "И этот человек:"+"id"+str(peer.id)+"("+first_name+")"
                            uch.append(message)
                        mes = random.choice(uch)
                        vk.method("message.send",{"peer_id":id,"message":mes})
                    elif  "Определи" in body.lower() or "Сколько" in body.lower():
                        random_choice = random.randrange(1,100,1)
                        vk.method("message.send", {"peer_id":id, "message":str(random_choice)+"%"})
                    elif "правда" in body.lower():
                        s = ["Да", "Нет"]
                        message = random.choise(s)
                        vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id":id, "message":mesage})
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Bot.py", line 7, in <module>
    messages = vk.method("messages.getConversationa",{"offaet": 0, "count": 1})
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Питон\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 646, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [3] Unknown method passed
[Finished in 1.2s]
```

Comment: добавьте код текстом пжл

Comment: @n1tr0xs ладно/

Comment: И трасе ошибки пожалуйста.

Comment: что вы пытаетесь получить строкой `messages = vk.method("messages.getConversationa",{"offaet": 0, "count": 1})` ? Есть 3 метода vkAPI, которые начинаются на `getConversationa`

Comment: @n1tr0xs можешь перечислить все три метода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вызываете метод, которого не существует. На [этой странице](https://vk.com/dev/messages) есть все доступные методы `messages.METHOD_NAME`

Comment: `message` **s**.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов спасибо, исправил.